# Java String.split("\\w*,\\w*+") to omit whitespace around the items?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I would expect

```
"Foo, Bar".split("\\s*,\\s*+")
```

to be split to `"Foo"` and `"Bar"`. However, what I get is `"Foo"` and `" Bar"`.

Why does not the `\\s*+` part match the space after comma?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `\\W` instead of `\\w`? And the current pattern doesn't give the result you're saying it gives.

Comment: Actually, \\s . Question to be deleted,  Ihave something screwed up in the code.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is this:

```
String[] s = "Foo, Bar".split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

`\s` matches any space-characters, `\w` matches any word-characters (that you wanna keep probably, not split on)